# Show html5 video controls only on Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ios6, html5-video

I have this video tag with flash fallback:

```
<video id="myvideo" width="480" height="224" autoplay preload="auto" loop poster="intro6.jpg">
<source src="intro6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="intro6.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="intro6.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<object width="480" height="224" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf">
<param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="autostart=true&amp;controlbar=hide&amp;image=intro6.jpg&amp;file=intro6.mp4&amp;repeat=always" />
<img src="intro6.jpg" width="480" height="224" />
</object>
</video>
```

And as you can see i do not have any controls, it's just a looping video that autoplays. This works great on desktop browsers, but not so much on Android and iOS.
So i need the controls to be visible on Android as it doesnt autoplay or loop.
And on iOS i need the video not to autoplay.

Is there a way to accomplish this with javascript? And keep in mind i don't know much javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest and most practical way is to check the user agent to see if you're on Android.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >=0) {
   document.getElementById('myvideo').controls = true;
}
```

In general, user agent sniffing is "frowned upon". It's *usually* best to use feature detection, since some far future version of the Android browser **might** support autoplay. But mobile browsers aren't usually very good at telling you when they don't support the video/audio spec.

Another way to do it is to check for events. In FF/Chrome/IE9+, the event will fire a series of events, including: `loadstart`, `progress`, `durationchange`, etc... up to `play` and `playing`. In the Android browser (at least, the old-ish version that I have), the video will instead fire a `stalled` event. You could look for `stalled` and then enable the controls. You could remove them again when you get the 'play' event.

```
var video = document.getElementById('myvideo'), started = false;
if (video && video.addEventListener) { //in case of IE < 9
    video.addEventListener('stalled', function() {
        if (!started) video.controls = true;
    }, false);
    video.addEventListener('play', function() {
        started = true;
        video.controls = false;
    }, false);
}
```

But there are other reasons why you might see that event, like a slow internet connection. So you'll still risk seeing the controls for a bit in a desktop browser until the video starts.

You don't need to worry about iOS. It won't autoplay, even if you want it to.